# Dynamic Control Array PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some php code that will create a field and then some other code where you put the information into the textbox and then in another php file it shows the data inputted in the textbox.

I have this code and screenshots.
This will create the fields like first name, age, etc.
Every time I click submit here, it goes to method post add.php. I am not providing the code for this here because it's ok.

Screenshot for index.php that adds fields:
[image: Screenshot for index.php that adds fields]

Code for adding fields

```html
<?php


function renderForm($fieldname, $fieldtype, $fieldgroup,$error)

{

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>FIELDS</title>

<style>

 label{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 0.5em;
 }

 </style>
</head>

<body>

<?php

if ($error != '')
{
echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
}

?>

<h1>ADD FIELDS</h1>

<form action="" method="post">

<label for = "fieldname"> Field Name:  <input type="text" name="fieldname"><br>
  <br></label>
  
 <label for = "fieldtype"> Field Type:  <select name="fieldtype">
  <option value="Text">Text</option>
  <option value="Date/Time">Date/Time Picker</option>
  <option value="Number">Number</option>
</select>
</label>
 <label for = "fieldgroup"> Field Group:  <select name="fieldgroup">
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
</select>
</label>
  
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  

</form>

<h1>VIEW</h1>
<?php

include('connect.php');


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fields")

or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";

echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Field Name</th> <th>Field Type</th><th>Field Group</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

echo "<tr>";

echo '<td>' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';

echo '<td>' . $row['fieldname'] . '</td>';

echo '<td>' . $row['fieldtype'] . '</td>';

echo '<td>' . $row['fieldgroup'] . '</td>';

echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '">Edit</a></td>';

echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '">Delete</a></td>';

echo "</tr>";

}


// close table>

echo "</table>";

?>

</body>
</html>

<?php

}

include('connect.php');


if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$fieldname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fieldname']));
$fieldtype = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fieldtype']));
$fieldgroup = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fieldgroup']));


if ($fieldname == '' || $fieldtype == '' || $fieldgroup == '')
{
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

renderForm($fieldname, $fieldtype, $fieldgroup, $error);
}
else
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO fields (fieldname,fieldtype,fieldgroup) VALUES('$fieldname','$fieldtype', '$fieldgroup')") or die (mysql_error());

header("Location: index.php");
}
}
else 
{
renderForm('','','','','');
}

?>
```

Screenshot for view.php:
[image: Screenshot for view.php]

This code is where it creates a form that shows the fields from before.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<title>View Records</title>

</head>

<body>


<?php
include('connect.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fields")

or die(mysql_error());

echo "<form action = 'test.php' method='POST'>
<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";

echo "<tr>  <th>Field Name</th> <th>Value</th></tr>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

echo "<tr>"; 
echo '<td> <name= "lbl[]" value ='. $row['ID'] . '"\>'.  $row['fieldname'] .  '</td>';
echo "<td> <input type ='text' name= 'val[]'> </td>"; 
 
echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<input type ='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'>";
echo "</form>"?>

</body>

</html>
```

After I click submit it goes to test.php and this is the code. This is where I have a problem. It doesn't show the values inserted in the view.php

```html
<?php 

 if(isset($_POST['val[]']))
 {
   $valid = $_POST['val[]'];
  
   
   for($a = 0; $a<$valid.length; $a++)
   {
    echo $valid[$a];
   }
 }

?>
```

Comment: Remove `[]` from your post val, make it look like this: `$_POST['val']`

Answer (score 0):

> Remove [] from your post val, make it look like this: $_POST['val']

try this

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['val']))
    {
            $valid = $_POST['val'];


            for($a = 0; $a<$valid.length; $a++)
            {
                echo $valid[$a];

            }

    }
```

?>

Comment: Thank you sir! Thank you so much! :) Sir, how to insert it to database?

Comment: you need rename val to include filed name as well to identify for which filed you need to insert that data

Comment: something like this 
echo "<td> <input type ='text' name= 'val[".$row['fieldname']."][]'> </td>";

Comment: how to do this sir?

Comment: to identify for which filed user is entering value

Comment: try with above name and print $_POST['val'] you will get idea

Comment: Can't get it sir. :(

Comment: how to do that sir? can't understand sir. thanks sir